# Automate firebase analytics using Appium

Tags: appium-java

Can we automate firebase analytics(events/views) triggered from android/ios apps using appium-java?

i have just triggered the events that needs to be automated and stuck with proceeding further...
Is it possible to link to firebase analytics and query the data to validate?

(or)

Is there any other way that we can catch the analytic events while triggering the events from app?

I have gone through many articles not getting correct answer

Please advise, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 -

1. Generate a build with unique build#.
2. After Appium execution for the events, initiate web browser through selenium.
3. Filter that specific  build version in Firebase and check the events

Option 2 -

1. Track network calls and validate the requests.